# Two Xmls input, One output with XSL transform

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm trying to write an XSL that basically need to take some values from one xml and other from another and output a XML. I've searched online for some solution and I found that I've to put  this `<xsl:variable name='file' select="'file:///C:/Users/file.xml'">` inside my input XML which is supposed to load another XML and store it into a variable but from this I dont know how to get the tags value of the document.

The **file.xml** is this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<silosMediaObject>
    <canBeDeleted>-1</canBeDeleted>
    <checkedOut>-1</checkedOut>
    <checkedOutBy>-1</checkedOutBy>
    <deleted>-1</deleted>
    <description>Traccia audio migrata da ASCN</description>
    <externalResourcePath>TEST/ASCN/lq/3763_2015-05-05.mp3</externalResourcePath>
    <fileName>3763_2015-05-05.mp3</fileName>
    <framesPerSecond>-1</framesPerSecond>
    <hasScheduledIngestion>false</hasScheduledIngestion>
    <isArchived>-1</isArchived>
    <isArchiving>-1</isArchiving>
    <isAvailable>-1</isAvailable>
    <isEncoding>-1</isEncoding>
    <isRestoring>-1</isRestoring>
    <isVerified>-1</isVerified>
    <mediaObjectId>-1</mediaObjectId>
    <mediaTypeId>-1</mediaTypeId>
    <mosId>4347</mosId>
    <resourceIsExternal>-1</resourceIsExternal>
    <sourceMediaObjectId>-1</sourceMediaObjectId>
    <state>AVAILABLE</state>
    <versionLinkId>-1</versionLinkId>
</silosMediaObject>
```

The Java class I'm using to transform the file is this one:

```
public class TestMain {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\Users\\xmltemplate_transformer.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\Users\\tobe_transformed.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\out.xml")));
    }
```

}

Comment: I get the impression you are trying to do this by searching for example code on the web and copying it without actually understanding it. That's not an efficient learning strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've searched online for some solution and I found that I've to put this `<xsl:variable name='file' select="'file:///C:/Users/file.xml'">` inside my input XML which is supposed to load another XML and store it into a variable

I don't know where you got that idea, but you're confused.  The `select` value is interpreted as an XPath expression.  Yours is a string literal containing a URL with the `file` scheme.  As far as XPath or XSLT is concerned, it is just a string.  One might do something further to cause the file designated by that URL to be parsed, but what you've presented has no such effect.

In particular, you might have wanted to do this:

```
<xsl:variable name='file' select="document('file:///C:/Users/file.xml')"/>
```

The `document()` function is the secret sauce that actually causes the designated file to be read and parsed (if possible); when used as shown, its result is a node set containing the root node of the resulting document, or an empty node set if the designated document cannot be parsed and the processor elects not to signal an error.

---

Note: when you say you put the `xsl:variable` "inside my input XML", I presume you mean at an appropriate place inside your (XML-based) XSL stylesheet.  If you actually mean that you have placed it in a different XML data file that you are processing, then it will have no direct effect there, other than to be included, as itself, in the input tree.

---

> but from this I dont know how to get the tags value of the document.

Having successfully parsed the file, you can use the resulting node set anywhere that XSLT expects an expression that evaluates to a node set.  In particular, within its scope, you can use a reference to the variable you've defined (`$file`) as an argument to XPath functions, or as a whole expression, such as the `select` expression of an `xsl:apply-templates`.  Since you haven't said what, specifically, you want to do with the contents, I cannot be any more specific myself.  See what you can do, and if you can't figure out the details then that could be a suitable topic for a new question.

Comment: thanks! that worked, you're right, I parsed the xml with this `<xsl:variable name="file"
  select="document('file:///C:/Users/file.xml')" />` and extracted the value of the tag I wanted with this `<xsl:value-of select="$file/silosMediaObject/canBeDeleted"/>`